# How do you build the 8g and 6g Go compilers for Go

Tags: compiler-construction, build, x86, go, x86-64

I'm writing software that will be somewhat widely deployed amongst Windows, Mac, and Linux systems on x86 and x86-64 architectures.  Whenever I set up the go compiler on my Mac and Linux systems I only ever get 6g built.  On Windows I just use the pre-built experimental binaries, which uses 8g.

When I get around to setting up build servers, I assume I need to also build 8g so I can produce 32 bit builds as well.  How do I set up 8g, in particular on a Mac (since they can be x86 or x64 depending on how old they are)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another poster said, use `GOARCH`. What he didn't say is that you don't need multiple directories.

Run `all.bash` twice, same `GOROOT`:

```
GOARCH=amd64 ./all.bash
GOARCH=386 ./all.bash
```

When you build something with `gomake` set up `GOARCH` if the default doesn't suit you

```
GOARCH=386 gomake
```

Unfortunately `goinstall` doesn't honor `GOARCH` yet.

Notice that gc compilers are always cross compiling. Once you have the compilers for the architecture you need, set `GOOS` and build the packages in `$GOROOT/src/pkg`, then you should be able to build your software targeting any operating system or architecture.

```
GOARCH=386 GOOS=windows gomake
```

Comment: Excellent, so what happens with all the "helper" commands like gofix, gofmt?  Do they just get built with the last GOARCH that I used?  So if I'm developing on an x64 machine, I might want to build 386 first and then switch to amd64 so that I have both compilers but my tools are all 64 bit.

Comment: Yes, helper tools will be built every time, so they'll have the GOARCH architecture, you might want to build 386 first and amd64 later if you want 64 bit helper tools.

Comment: Note this answer is **very** out of date. There is no `gomake` or `goinstall` anymore. `go build` and `go install` handle `GOOS` and `GOARCH` just fine and there is no need for multiple directories (other than the ones that `go install` will create for you).

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the environment variable `GOARCH` to `386` instead of probably automatically chosen `amd64` by the `all.bash` build script. See [environment variables](http://golang.org/doc/install.html#environment) in Go documentation for details.

Comment: So what if you wish to build/install both the 32 and 64 bit binaries?  Build them in separate directories and change the vars between builds???  I suppose that'll work.  Sounds like a good opportunity for a script.