# Compile 32 bit binary on 64 bit system

Tags: windows, go

I've coded a Go program in a 64 bit system but I want to compile a 32 bit binary!

The 64 bit binary is working just great but I have no idea how to create a 32 bit binary.

How can I do it?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm not using using any IDE. Just a text editor and the command line. Anyway, is it possible to compile go code in VS?

Comment: Try using the GOARCH environment variable as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786492/how-do-you-build-the-8g-and-6g-go-compilers-for-go

Comment: I set GOARCH and GOOS environment variables but I'm getting this error: "go build runtime: exec: "C:\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_amd64\\8g.exe": GetFileAttri
butesEx C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\8g.exe: winapi error #2"

Comment: You first have to run make.bat with GOARCH set to 386 to recompile go for x86.

Comment: Seems like someone had the same problem: https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/issues/211 If some of you know how to delete Sublime Text data I'd thank you so much..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you built your Go from source, then you can build any additional compilers and libraries for any CPU and OS. If you are on windows/amd64 and want to build for windows/386, then this will build everything you need to compile for windows/386:

```
set GOARCH=386  
cd %GOROOT%\src  
make.bat --no-clean
```

Once you have done that, you can build your windows/386 executable with:

```
set GOARCH=386  
cd %YOUR_PROG_DIR%  
go build
```

Since you are on windows/amd64, you should be able to even run / test your windows/386 programs too. Just make sure to `set GOARCH=386` before you invoke any commands for windows/386.

One caveat: this does not support `cgo`, so you cannot use any packages that use `cgo`.

Comment: If you run "go build -a" instead, do you still need to run "make.bat" inside the GOROOT directory?

Comment: @noj I am not clear about your question? But you run make.bat once to build all compilers and standard packages. After that you can just use them.

Comment: `make.bat` is old version 1.4 ... how to make clean to new version 1.8.3?

Answer (score 9):

The way I have achieved this (without any compiling of the compiler) on my Windows 7 64 bit PC was first having the windows amd64 installed, then [download 32bit](https://golang.org/dl/) zip and unpack to a second folder:

```
\go\go32
\go\go64
```

By then adjusting the `PATH` and the `GOROOT` inside my command prompt window as follows:

```
set PATH=\go\go32;%PATH%
set GOROOT=\go\go32\
```

Then I went back and recompiled my app that was previously compiling using the 64 bit.  All this can be setup in a batch if you want to switch between regularly.

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to set the PATH to the go32\BIN folder.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've finally solved the problem! Here it is how I did it(I was miserably failing actually!).

- The first thing I did was to download GCC from http://www.mingw.org/.
- Next I added **C:\MinGW\bin** to the **PATH** environment variable(I'm assuming that MinGW is installed in C:\MinGw)
- Next thing before running **go build/go install** is to set the enviroment variables.
- Open the command prompt and cd to C:\Go\src and run all.bat from the command line.
- Set **GOOS**, **GOARCH** and **CGO_ENABLED** to **windows**, **386** and **0** respectively! (you should also set GOPATH to the path where your current Go project is).
- Next run make.bat and make.bat --no-clean
  After that you can build your project for 32 bit systems! I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

My Go version is 1.14 ,I  change make.bat as follow:

```
:: if "x%GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP%"=="x" set GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Go1.4
```

Change GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP to my Go's root:

```
if "x%GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP%"=="x" set  GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=D:\Go
```

after that I got this error

```
go tool dist: unknown $goarch 386
```

then I set GOOS and GOARCH

```
setlocal
set GOROOT=%GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP%
set GOOS=
set GOARCH=
set GOBIN=
set GO111MODULE=off
"%GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP%\bin\go.exe" build -o cmd\dist\dist.exe .\cmd\dist
endlocal
```

set GOOS AND GOARCH as follow

```
setlocal
set GOROOT=%GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP%
set GOOS=windows
set GOARCH=386
set GOBIN=
set GO111MODULE=off
"%GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP%\bin\go.exe" build -o cmd\dist\dist.exe .\cmd\dist
endlocal
```

But I got error this is not a 32bit program.

Comment: Hi @Hui I have no idea why you modified this file.I just set GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP variable to c:\go (as the output said: _"Set GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP to a working Go tree"_